# How to print Racket structs

Tags: racket

Is there any way to control how a struct is printed?

For example if I have a transparent struct containing an image:

```
(struct photo (label image-data) #:transparent)
```

But I don't want to print the `image-data` field.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

I want to extend Ben's answer a bit. You can also combine [`gen:custom-write`](http://docs.racket-lang.org/reference/Printer_Extension.html?q=gen%3Acustom-write#%28def._%28%28lib._racket%2Fprivate%2Fbase..rkt%29._gen~3acustom-write%29%29) with [`make-constructor-style-printer`](http://docs.racket-lang.org/reference/structutils.html?q=make-constructor-style-printer#%28def._%28%28lib._racket%2Fstruct..rkt%29._make-constructor-style-printer%29%29) to make the struct printing significantly easier. This function handles the differences between printing, writing, quote depth, and output port for you.

Extending his example gives:

```
#lang racket
(require pict
         racket/struct)

(struct photo (label image-data)
  #:transparent
  #:methods gen:custom-write
  [(define write-proc
     (make-constructor-style-printer
       (lambda (obj) 'photo)
       (lambda (obj) (list (photo-label obj)))))])

(displayln (photo "fish" (standard-fish 100 100)))
;; Prints #<photo: fish>

(println (photo "fish" (standard-fish 100 100)))
;; Prints (photo "fish")
```

Now `write`, `display`, and `print` all work as you would expect

Answer (score 8):

Yes! Use the [`gen:custom-write`](http://docs.racket-lang.org/reference/Printer_Extension.html#%28def._%28%28lib._racket%2Fprivate%2Fbase..rkt%29._gen~3acustom-write%29%29) generic interface.

```
#lang racket
(require pict)

(struct photo (label image-data)
  #:transparent
  #:methods gen:custom-write
  [(define (write-proc photo-val output-port output-mode)
     (fprintf output-port "#<photo:~a>" (photo-label photo-val)))])

(photo "fish" (standard-fish 100 100))
;; Prints "#<photo:fish>"
```

The first argument to `write-proc` is the struct to be printed.
The second argument is the port to print to.
The third argument suggests how the context wants the value printed, see the docs:
http://docs.racket-lang.org/reference/Printer_Extension.html#%28def._%28%28lib._racket%2Fprivate%2Fbase..rkt%29._gen~3acustom-write%29%29